# coding raspberry pi python beautifulsoup pi-lite facebook like counter

Tags: python, facebook, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a raspberry pi display on the pi-lite the number of facebook likes of a page. I feel that I have all the pieces, but am too much of a n00b to put them all together. Here is how I thought I would go about it:
- use beautiful soup to retrieve PagesLikesCountDOMID from the FB page
- display that number using pi-lite.

I'm stuck at how to approach that. I typically find some code, modify it, and make it work. I can't seem to find a good starting point for this one. Anybody have any good starting points? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks everyone. Between the pi-lite Hello World script and this like counter script http://www.idiotinside.com/2015/02/13/get-number-of-likes-of-a-facebook-page-using-graph-api-in-python/, I was able to get it working. I'm now trying to figure out how to not have the access token expire. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have a look at the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading

You can request number of page likes like the following:

```
/{page_id}?fields=likes&access_token={app_access_token}
```

so for example

```
/40796308305?fields=likes&access_token={app_access_token}
```

will show the likes count of the CocaCola page. You'll need to create an app to be able to get an app access token.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=40796308305%3Ffields%3Dlikes
- https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any experience with Raspberry Pi's (a little with Arduino's) but you're spot on with how you have started. Taking working code and modifying it is a great way to get started.

Here's a general tip though, something that I still do. When dealing with a project with many moving parts, break it down by part. You have two major parts here, a web scraper (for the FB likes) and then a UI to visualize that value. I would create a script that only collects FB likes and then make another one that only displays a value on the pi-lite.

---

**Web Scraper Part**

I've used [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for all of my BS4 work that I've done and it's been able to answer almost all of my questions, with SO filling in the gaps. I'm confident you can handle that and I can help answer specific questions about BS4.

---

**Pi-Lite Part**

Here is a [*hello world* example](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/09/pi-lite-led-matrix-board-python-hello-world-example/) for the pi-lite. You may have ran into this already but it seems like a good starting point but like I said, I don't have any experience with it.

Hope some of this helps you.

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed by its ToS... Also, there's an API for the use case

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the api and hello world part .Agreed on breaking it down into parts.